# htaccess disable direct access to directories

Tags: .htaccess

is there a way to disable direct access to some directory files

Like I have images in the image directory of my website, I would surely want to load the images on the site itself, but I don't want to let people write for example

```
http://mydomain.com/images/zzz.png
```

and see the image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This by no means is fool-proof.  It won't allow someone to type in the url of an image, but you can still, in FireFox for example, right-click and "View Image" and it will show it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule \.(jpg|gif|png)$ - [F]
```

Pretty basic, I think with a little more work, it would be possible to completely exclude.

Hope it helps....

Comment: thanks for trying to help, it works for direct access to the image but my issue is that on the website some images aren't appearing anymore